# Visual Studio type discovery service is painfully slow

Tags: visual-studio-2010, envdte

I have followed this [blog post](http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/retrieving-available-types-in-current-project-and-its-references-withoult-locking/) (which proved to be awesome) in order to retrieve a type (types) from the project that inherit from a certain base class.

This usually work fine, however when "discovering" types from an Web Application it can be really slow. It actually took over 7 minutes at some point. The problem is I can't find exact steps for reproducing this behaviour.

Has anyone stumbled upon something similar or can explain what is going on behind the curtain. Digging into the actual class that does it using Reflector did not help much. (It's the VSTypeResolutionService class from the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.dll assembly)